# Is there a fast way to reinitialize or clear etcd keyspace for testing?

Tags: ruby, rspec, etcd

I am writing a small ruby application that utilizes etcd via the [etcd-ruby](https://github.com/ranjib/etcd-ruby) gem to coordinate activities across a cluster.

One problem I have is how to write specs for it.

My first approach was to attempt to mock out the etcd calls at the client level, however this is sub-optimal because the responses returned by the client are quite complex with metadata.  I thought about writing a wrapper over the etcd client to strip away the metadata and make a mocking approach easier, but the problem is the algorithm does depend on this metadata at times, so the abstraction becomes very leaky and just a painful layer of indirection.

Another approach is to use VCR to record actual requests.  This has the benefit of allowing specs to run without etcd, but it becomes a mess of initializing state and managing cassettes.

This brings me to my question. etcd is fast enough as a solo node that it seems easiest and most straightforward to just use it directly in tests and not attempt to stub it at all.  The only problem here is that I can't see any easy way to clear the keyspace between tests.  Recursive delete on the root key is not allowed.  Also, this doesn't reset the indices.  I checked the `etcd-ruby` gem specs, and it appears to bypass the issue by using keys based on uuids so that keys simply never collide.  I suppose that is a viable approach, but is there something better?

Answer (score 0):

I would test against an [etcd docker container](https://quay.io/repository/coreos/etcd) which you can tear down and restore very quickly for tests.